# Scraping images from urls in a nested item in Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I havea Scrapy Spider set up. I have urls that I scrape and then I store multiple results by url. I have nested arrays in each item.
I'd like to use images urls contained in these items to download images but I can't do that.

```
    def init(self, *args, **kwargs):
    data_file = pkgutil.get_data(
    "auctions_results", "json/input/demo_db_urls_glenmarch.json")
    self.data = json.loads(data_file)

def start_requests(self):
    for item in self.data:
        request = scrapy.Request(item['gm_url'], callback=self.parse)
        request.meta['item'] = item
        yield request

def parse(self, response):
    item = response.meta['item']
    item['results'] = []

    for caritem in response.css("div.car-item-border"):
        data = AuctionItem()

        data["marque"] = caritem.css("div.make::text").extract_first().strip().split(" ", 2)[1]
        data["model"] = caritem.css("div.make::text").extract_first().strip().split(" ", 2)[2]
        data["model_year"] = caritem.css("div.make::text").extract_first().strip().split(" ", 1)[0]
        data["price_str"] = caritem.css("div.price::text").extract_first().strip().replace(",", " ")

        if caritem.css("div.price::text").extract_first().find("Estimate"):
            data["price_int"] = re.sub("\D", "", data["price_str"])
            data["price_int"] = int(data["price_int"])
            data["price_currency"] = re.sub(
                "[0-9]", "", data["price_str"]).replace(" ", "")
            data["sold"] = True
        else:
            data["price_int"] = None
            data["price_currency"] = None
            data["sold"] = False

        data["auction_house"] = caritem.css("div.auctionHouse::text").extract_first().split("-", 1)[0].strip()
        data["auction_country"] = caritem.css("div.auctionHouse::text").extract_first().rsplit(",", 1)[1].strip()
        data["auction_date"] = caritem.css("div.date::text").extract_first().replace(",", "").strip()

        if " - " in data["auction_date"]:
            auctiondate = re.sub(r".*-", "", data["auction_date"]).strip()
            data["auction_datetime"] = datetime.strptime(auctiondate, '%d %B %Y').date()
        else:
            data["auction_datetime"] = datetime.strptime(data["auction_date"], '%d %B %Y').date()

        auctionurl = caritem.css("div.view-auction a::attr(href)").extract_first()
        if auctionurl != None and "/auction-cars/show-backup-image" not in auctionurl:
            data["auction_url"] = caritem.css("div.view-auction a::attr(href)").extract_first()
        else :
            data["auction_url"] = None

        data["image_urls"] = caritem.css("div.view-auction a img::attr(src)").extract_first()

        item['results'].append(data)

    yield item`
```

My output in JSON look like this:

```
{ "objectID": 10202, "gm_url": "myurl", "results": [{ "marque": "Alfa", "model": "Romeo Giulia Sprint GT Veloce 1600", "model_year": "1966", "price_str": "€49 280", "price_int": 49280, "price_currency": "€", "sold": true, "auction_house": "RM Sotheby's", "auction_country": "Italy", "auction_date": "25 - 27 November 2016", "auction_datetime": "2016-11-27", "auction_url": null, "image_urls": "imagesurl" }, { "marque": "Alfa", "model": "Romeo Giulia Sprint GT Veloce Coupe", "model_year": "1966", "price_str": "€46 000", "price_int": 46000, "price_currency": "€", "sold": true, "auction_house": "Bonhams", "auction_country": "France", "auction_date": "6 February 2014", "auction_datetime": "2014-02-06", "auction_url": "https://www.bonhams.com//auctions/21768/lot/434/?category=list&length=100000&page=1", "image_urls": "imagesurl" }] }
```

How can I download images from "images_urls" ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you [enable Images Pipeline](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/media-pipeline.html#enabling-your-media-pipeline)?

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {'scrapy.pipelines.images.ImagesPipeline': 1}
```

Comment: What is your `ROBOTSTXT_OBEY` (couple of times I have a rule that didn't allow to download images)? Can you show an output log for a single item?

Comment: It is false. I think it's because the image_urls is in a nested item but I don't know how to code the pipeline.

Comment: We can't help you without output log.

Answer (score 0):

Image pipelines expect the `image_urls` field on the root item.

While you can [override the field name used](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/media-pipeline.html#usage-example), for your use case that will not be enough, as you want to handle multiple fields per item.

So, as per the documentation:

> If you need something more complex and want to override the custom pipeline behaviour, see [Extending the Media Pipelines](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/media-pipeline.html#topics-media-pipeline-override).